# No Scopes Specified - Google_Auth_Exception

Tags: symfony, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am applying [this tutorial](https://github.com/HappyR/GoogleAnalyticsBundle) into symfony 2.4, I've finished the setup in the config.yml and everything, I managed to visit the admin/google/analytics page, but the problem is when I tried to authenticate with the parameters I've created in the config.yml file, it is searching for the scope, here is the parameters.

```
happy_r_google_analytics:
    host: www.example.com
    profile_id: MyProfileId
    tracker_id: UA-TRACKER-ID
    token_file_path: %kernel.root_dir%/var/storage
happy_r_google_api:
    application_name: Project Default Service Account
    oauth2_client_id: OAuthClientID
    oauth2_client_secret: OAuthClientSecret
    oauth2_redirect_uri: http://www.example.com/app_local.php/admin/google/analytics/oauth2callback
    developer_key: DevelopperKey
    site_name: http://www.example.com
```

I think there's no problem here, I've got no idea where I can set the scope so the google Api client can set it to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a scope. If you use Google Auth, check [Authorization scopes](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes) for it.

You must do something like:

```
    $googleClient = new \Google_Client();
    $googleClient->setScopes(array(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    ));
```

Comment: I am trying to implement a server to server OAuth2 I think the scopes must not be from that. I'll just find other tutorials on how I can get the analytic datas, Your answer is correct for those people implementing web applications, service accounts for server to server but it's quite hard to implement in symfony.

Comment: Maybe you better try to realize it manually with controllers or services and don't use vendor bundles?

Comment: Well after a long research I've encountered the GAPI for Google Analytics where I've created it as an object for my bundle and call it in my controllers, so I guess I'll leave the vendor Bundles for now. cheers!